¿Qué tipo de arreglo o cadena se puede considerar lo siguiente?
Estoy analizando una base de datos y la tabla productos tiene un campo llamado json_vehicles y ahí se almacena una cadena con vehículos de un producto, pero tiene la siguiente estructura:
"marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"150","year":"2015-2019","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"200","year":"2015-2019"

¿Qué tipo de arreglo o json es este y cómo se puede leer o mostrar en PHP o javascript?

¿La cadena no tiene llaves alrededor {}?

No, no tiene llaves

Convendría pensar en normalizar esos datos, pasándolas a una tabla con las columnas marca, submarca, motor y year y luego guardar una fila por cada dato. Si en algún contexto necesitas una salida en forma de json lo puedes producir fácilmente con las funciones propias de MySQL o a mano si tuvieras una versión muy antigua.  Podríamos pensar también en tablas relacionales para no guardar tantas veces datos repetitivos como marca y otros, usando IDs.

Pues se podria decir que ya encontre una solución para convertir esa cadena en un json, estuve investigando, metiendome a varios foros y lo que hice en cierta manera fue con conocimiento mio y con partes de código de diferentes autores, y salio lo siguiente:
<?php
$cadena = '"marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"150","year":"2015-2019","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"200","year":"2015-2019"';
$cadena = '[{'.$cadena;     
$arr=explode(",",$cadena); 
$json = "";
$contador = 0;
$segundoContador = 1;
foreach ($arr as $key) {
     
     $segundoContador = $segundoContador + 1;
     
     if($segundoContador == 5){
       $json = $json.$arr[$contador].'},{';
       $segundoContador = 1;
     }else{
        $json = $json.$arr[$contador].',';
     }
     
     $contador = $contador + 1;
 }
 
 $json = substr($json, 0, -2);
 
 $json = $json.']';
 
echo $json;
?>

De esta manera solucione mi problema y es que como tengo que hacer eso para 14,000 articulos en una tabla de una base de datos con cadenas como esta:
"marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"YZF","motor":"600 CC","year":"1991-1992","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FSZ","motor":"1000 CC","year":"1991-1992","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"R6","motor":"600 CC","year":"1991-1992","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZS","motor":"600 CC","year":"1991-1992","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"MT-07","motor":"7300 CC","year":"1991-1992","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"MT-09","motor":"900 CC","year":"1991-1992","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"ZSF","motor":"400 CC","year":"1991-1992","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"YZF-RJ","motor":"600 CC","year":"1997-2007","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"YZF-RRL (R6)","motor":"600 CC","year":"1999-2004","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"YZF R6S","motor":"600 CC","year":"2006-2009","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ6","motor":"600 CC","year":"2007-2009","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"YZF R7 OWO2","motor":"750 CC","year":"1999-2001","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZS","motor":"1000 CC","year":"2001-2005","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"YZF-RJ","motor":"1000 CC","year":"1997-1997","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"YZF (R1)","motor":"1000 CC","year":"1998-2002","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZS","motor":"1000 CC","year":"2001-2005","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV ROAD STAR SILVERADOS","motor":"1700 CC","year":"2008-2011","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"ROAD STAR MIDNIGHT WARRIOR","motor":"1700 CC","year":"2005-2005","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"ROAD STAR","motor":"1700","year":"2006-2006","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV ROAD STAR (CAST WHEEL)","motor":"1700 CC","year":"2007-2010","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV ROAD STAR MIDNIGHT","motor":"1700 CC","year":"2004-2007","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV ROAD STAR WARRIOR","motor":"1700 CC","year":"2002-2005","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV ROADLINER","motor":"1900 CC","year":"2006-2007","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV ROADLINER MIDNIGHT","motor":"1900 CC","year":"2006-2009","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"VX ROADLINER S","motor":"1900 CC","year":"2006-2010","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV STRATOLINER","motor":"1900 CC","year":"2006-2009","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV STRATOLINER MIDNIGHT","motor":"1900 CC","year":"2006-2008","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV STRATOLINER S","motor":"1900 CC","year":"2006-2010","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV STRATOLINER DELUXE ","motor":"1900 CC","year":"2008-2011","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"XV RAIDER","motor":"1900 CC","year":"2008-2011"
o hasta 4 veces mas grandes, por eso necesitaba una solucion dinamica y con este fragmento ya puedo hacerlo, espero que algún día a alguien le pueda funcionar
A lo mejor no es el mejor código pero me funciono

Es una cadena JSON mal formada; debería ser un array de objetos.
Corrígela así:
[
  {"marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"150","year":"2015-2019"},
  {"marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"200","year":"2015-2019"}
]

En PHP o JavaScript, puedes leerla con json_decode() o JSON.parse().

Ya que solucionaste tu problema, publico mi intento solo por deporte.
No olvides (pasadas las 24Hs) de marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, para que no quede como una pregunta sin respuesta válida.
Si se trata solo de mostrar los datos, puedes usar lo siguiente:


let entrada = '"marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"150","year":"2015-2019","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"200","year":"2015-2019"';

let data = entrada.split( "," );

for( let i = 0; i < data.length;  ) {
   for( let k = 0; k < 4; k++, i++ ) {
  let dataEspecifica = data[ i ].replaceAll( '"', '' ).split( ":" );
  console.log( dataEspecifica[ 0 ] + ": " + dataEspecifica[ 1 ] );
   }
   console.log( "" );
}



Ahora si lo que quieres es transformarlo en un 'Json' válido, prueba con esto:


let entrada = '"marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"150","year":"2015-2019","marca":"Yamaha","submarca":"FZ","motor":"200","year":"2015-2019"';

let data = entrada.split( "," );
let salida = "[\n";

for( let i = 0; i < data.length;  ) {
   salida += "    {";
   for( let k = 0; k < 4; k++, i++ ) {
      salida += data[ i ] + ",";
   }
   salida = salida.substring( 0, salida.length -1 );
   salida += "},\n";
}
salida = salida.substring( 0, salida.length -2 ) + "\n]";

console.log( salida );



